# PSpice Simulation of CE8301

Tags: voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit, dc-dc-converter, simulation, pspice

I have been working on a project that requires me to boost 1V to 5V. I have found a ready-to-use boost regulator that gets the job done. The problem is that I need to get the circuit simulated on OrCad Pspice but the CE8301 CMOS PFM-control
step-up switching DC/DC converter is not included in the library.

I have the block diagram of CE8301. Is there a way to add this component by hand to PSspice library so that I can simulate the circuit below.

Also, block diagram is included in the attachments.

[image: Circuit that needs to simulated]

[image: Block Diagram]

Comment: Why exactly do you want to simulate it? Unless you have a model from the manufacturer (and even then maybe not) you're unlikely to be able to learn much. Making a realistic model is non-trivial and requires inside information and/or a lot of measurements.

Comment: This is a part of my senior project. My professor told me to include simulation results in the progress report. 
Yes, you are right, it requires inside information, which I do not have. That's exactly why I am confused about this whole simulation process.

Comment: P.S. [These guys](http://www.aeng.com/custom-models-list.htm) have a model of the On Semi NCP1402. $2K USD for the library, which is fairly modest in comparison to PSPICE itself.

Comment: unless the fine details are necessary you can replace it with a voltage source, perhaps with some noise added if you require that. There's no need to simulate every single part.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you care about the specific function of this particles regulator, you would model this as a 5v voltage source.  When you build the schematic, you would read the data sheet, follow the directions and recommndations, and expect to reach the speed functionality.

You model because there are question you'd like to ask the model -  not because it's there or because you can.  Unless the circuit you're trying to simulate depends on the nuances of the regulator, there is no reason to include the regulator in your simulation.